# To retrive yesterday's data and insert as today's data

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a php mysql project.
In which the project has two tables

1. Product table
2. daily sales

In which daily sales are calculated as per the stock. In which old_balance gets updated by the yesterday's current balance. My code is like this.

```
if($oldbal==NULL && $datecur== 'systemdate'){
  $datecur = $datecur - 1;
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT current from sales where sales.date='$datecur'");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $oldbal=$row['current'];
    $total=$oldbal + $receipt;
    $sql="INSERT INTO sales (pcode,oldbal,receipt,total,current,date)
      VALUES ('$_POST[pcode]','$oldbal','$_POST[receipt]','$total','$_POST[current]','$_POST[date]')";
  }
}
else{
  $total=$oldbal + $receipt;
  $sql="INSERT INTO sales (pcode,oldbal,receipt,total,current,date)
  VALUES ('$_POST[pcode]','$_POST[oldbal]','$_POST[receipt]','$total','$_POST[current]','$_POST[date');
}
```

In this part I am asking the user not to enter Old_balance data and checking today's date, and I fetch current balance from data base in order to insert as the new tuple.

Comment: Your code block is incomplete, could you please include code until the closing brace of your first `if`?

Comment: sure give me a minute

Comment: Whats your problem here ?

Comment: I need to fetch current balance (yerterday's balance) When I update a row each row will get updated when entered. If i don't retreive yesterdays data all the data gets updated.